# PostSharp: Method *** should be annotated with a selector custom attribute because it is a master handler

Tags: postsharp

This code throw error: `Method ...OnEntry(...) should be annotated with a selector custom attribute because it is a master handler`.

```
[PSerializable]
public class LogRequestAttribute : MethodLevelAspect, IAspectProvider {
    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object target) {
        yield return new AspectInstance( target, new LogPlainRequest() );
    }
}

[PSerializable]
public class LogPlainRequest : IMethodLevelAspect {
    public void RuntimeInitialize(MethodBase method) {
    }
    [OnMethodEntryAdvice]
    public void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args) {
    }
}
```

What is it error meaning? And what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine several related advices into one group (e.g. `OnEntry`, `OnExit`). This is what [OnMethodBoundaryAspect](https://doc.postsharp.net/method-decorator) does for you automatically. After you've grouped the advices you need to designate one of them as a "master advice". The properties and the *pointcut* of the group must be set on the master advice.

The pointcut assigned to the master advice acts as a selector of the advice's target element. The [SelfPointcut](https://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_advices_selfpointcut), for example, simply selects the target of the aspect as the target of the advice. You can find more info and different pointcut kinds in the docs:
https://doc.postsharp.net/advices

In the example above you can apply the `[SelfPointcut]` attribute to the `OnEntry` method to get rid of the error message.

```
[PSerializable]
public class LogPlainRequest : IMethodLevelAspect {
    public void RuntimeInitialize(MethodBase method) {
    }

    [OnMethodEntryAdvice]
    [SelfPointcut]
    public void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args) {
    }
}
```